# How to automate the activation of Flash plug-in using selenium firefox geckodriver?

Tags: python, selenium, flash, ui-automation, pyvirtualdisplay

When I try to open a page with flash using an automated python script with Selenium I reach the page in the picture below. And I cannot pass.

[image: Flash Activation Page]

It's a remote server running Ubuntu 16.04, without access to a monitor or a keyboard/mouse.

Python version: 3.5.2

Selenium version: 3.14.1

Geckodriver 0.26.0

Follows my code:

```
import pyvirtualdisplay
print ("pyvirtualdisplay Display Version: %s" % (pyvirtualdisplay.__version__))
from selenium import webdriver
print ("Selenium webdriver Version: %s" % (webdriver.__version__))

display = pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.native_events_enabled = False
profile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 2)
profile.set_preference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so","true")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
url = 'https://www.ultrasounds.com/US.html'
driver.get(url)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
display.stop()
quit()
```

Here's the output:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Apr 16 2020, 17:47:17)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyvirtualdisplay
>>> print ("pyvirtualdisplay Display Version: %s" % (pyvirtualdisplay.__version__))
pyvirtualdisplay Display Version: 0.2.4
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> print ("Selenium webdriver Version: %s" % (webdriver.__version__))
Selenium webdriver Version: 3.14.1
>>>
>>> display = pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
>>> display.start()
<Display cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '800x600x24', ':1001'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '800x600x24', ':1001'] oserror=None return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>
>>>
>>> profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
>>> profile.native_events_enabled = False
>>> profile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 2)
>>> profile.set_preference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so","true")
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

>>> driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
>>> url = 'https://www.ultrasounds.com/US.html'
>>> driver.get(url)
>>>
>>>
>>> import pyautogui
>>> im1 = pyautogui.screenshot('flash_activation_page.jpg')
>>> driver.close()
>>> driver.quit()
>>> display.stop()
<Display cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '800x600x24', ':1001'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '800x600x24', ':1001'] oserror=None return_code=0 stdout="" stderr="" timeout_happened=False>
>>>
```

Comment: Try right-clicking on something on the flash activation page. Is there an "Inspect Element" option? If so, click that. I bet the browser generates its own DOM.

Comment: I cannot click, I do not have a mouse/keyboard/monitor on this server. I can only inspect it through python.

Comment: Try using **PyMouse** or **pyAutoGUI** to send the clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Firefox` >= `69`, you won't be able to do that:

> *The setting to always activate the Adobe Flash plugin was removed in
>   Firefox 69. See [this compatibility document](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2019/flash-player-can-no-longer-always-be-activated/)
>   for details.*

---

## Flash Player can no longer always be activated

Published: June 15, 2019

Categories: [Plug-ins](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/categories/plugins/)

Releases: [Firefox 69](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/releases/69/)

### Description

As part of the ongoing [Flash plug-in support deprecation](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2018/flash-plug-in-support-will-be-removed-in-2020/), Firefox 69 has removed the “Always Activate” option from the page notification dialog and the “Remember this decision” option from the Add-on Manager. It means, from now on, Firefox will ask the user every time if they want to show Flash content on a website during a browser session, and the user won’t be able to change this behaviour.

At the time of this writing, only half of Firefox users have Flash Player installed according to [Firefox Public Data Report](https://data.firefox.com/dashboard/hardware), and the number is steadily decreasing. Given that the Flash support will be removed from Firefox and other browsers in 2020, you are strongly encouraged to make a migration plan as soon as possible if your site still relies on any Flash content including legacy video players.

Comment: @vc.One Appreciated !